# Local network computers suddenly not showing under network

Tags: networking, windows-10, local

I've a basic local network with 3 windows 10 computers linked using ethernet : CP1, CP2, CP3.
All was fine but since thursday, and after a windows update, one of the computer, CP2, does not see the others anymore.

What is weird is CP1 & CP3 see all 3 computers under network, including CP2.
But CP2 doesn't see any.

Also while on CP2 I can ping the other computers just fine.

I even created a homegroup but it doesn't fix the issue, CP2 see CP1 and CP3 in homegroup but not in network, although i now see media folder for CP1 under network.

Been searching the net and trying quite a few things but nothing works, I'm close to calling it quit and reformating the computer as it was working fine till thursday.

Comment: Are they all in the same Workgroup?

Comment: Same workgroup and I can ping them just fine with cmd

Comment: Did you ensure that within the _Network and Sharing Center_ that CP2 isn't configured to use a Public network profile?

Comment: Yep CP2 is also on private network